# Argument of \__cmd_expandable_grab_D:NNNwNNn has an extra }. Can't run my document

Tags: latex, tex, miktex

`enter code here`This is my code: (I've removed some lines just because of data). Today I've been just working with pdfs and tried to add there some tables converted to PDF but afterword error just poped up. I'm looking straight up for you answears.

My error is:
! Argument of __cmd_expandable_grab_D:NNNwNNn has an extra }.

\par
l.38 \section{^^c3^^9avod}

```
% Metódy inžinierskej práce

\documentclass[10pt,twoside,slovak,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[IL2]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{cite}

\pagestyle{headings}

\title{Herný dizajn\thanks{Semestrálny projekt v predmete Metódy inžinierskej práce, ak. rok 2022/23, vedenie: Ing. Zuzana Špitálová}} 

\author{Adam Melničák\\[2pt]
    {\small Slovenská technická univerzita v Bratislave}\\
    {\small Fakulta informatiky a informačných technológií}\\
    {\small \texttt{ferko@xxx.sk}}
    }

\date{\small 6. november 2022}



\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
V dnešnej dobe sú hry oblasťou, ktorá je veľmi blízka mladým ľuďom.
\end{abstract}



\section{Úvod}
Gamifikácia je v dnešnej dobe častokrát mylne chápaný pojem,  ktorý si ľudia zamieňajú so samotnými hrami.  Tento pojem primárne vystihuje zapájanie herných prvkov do neherných oblastí. Aj keď práve táto technika je s hrami úzko spojená, nie je chápaná ako hra sama o sebe.

\section{Prvky herného dizajnu}
Pri aplikácii gamifikácie sú prvky herného dizajnu kľúčom k úspechu. Pojem herný dizajnér v praxi, označuje pracovné pozície, ktorých hlavnou úlohou je navrhovať pravidlá správania sa vecí v hre a potom tieto pravidlá zvyčajne implementovať.

\subsection{Definícia cieľa hry}
Napriek veľkému počtu definícii hier sa vedci vo všeobecnosti zhodujú na tom,  že hry majú ciele.

\subsubsection{Výhra}
Jedným zo základných cieľov hry je výhra.

\subsubsection{Dokončenie}
Existujú hry, ktoré majú vopred navrhnutý a určený záver (závery), ale nemajú explicitné, súťažné hodnotenie, pri ich ukončení.

\subsubsection{Predĺženie}
Predĺženie patrí do kategórie hier, kde daná hra nemá konečný stav. Cieľom týchto hier je oddialiť ich záver nekonečným počtom životov.  Príkladom takejto hry je World of Warcraft (Blizzard 2004), ktorá je svetovým fenoménom medzi multiplayerovými hrami a držiteľom svetových ocenení.  Tieto hry nemajú koniec a o ich ukončení rozhoduje hráč. Medzi tento typ hier zaraďujeme aj hry s cieľom, ktorý však nie je možné dosiahnuť, keďže ich vývojári neustále dopĺňajú o nové úrovne. Jednou z takých hier je Don't Starve (Klei Entertainment 2013), ktorá je založená na prežití čo najväčšieho počtu dní. Hry s cieľom predĺženia nie je možné dokončiť a ich hlavným cieľom je predĺženie herného zážitku.

\subsection{Interakcia s hráčmi}
Masívne multiplayerová online hra na hrdinov je žáner PC hry, ktorá umožňuje stovkám alebo tisícom geograficky rozmiestnených hráčov, ktorí môžu súčasne hrať na internete.  Hranie hier tohto typu zahŕňa kolektívnu spoluprácu pri plnení vzájomných úloh, čo výrazne napomáha pri riešení skupinových problémov. Takýto hráči sa častokrát chcú neustále zlepšovať a preto pátrajú po informáciach aj na online fórach, kde s ostatnými zdieľajú rôzne taktiky. Ďalšou formou interakcie pri hraní multiplayerových hier je možnosť zapojenia sa do klanov, cechov alebo tímov, kde majú hráči možnosť navzájom komunikovať prostredníctvom chatu. Teória spolupatričnosti naznačuje, že ľudia majú základnú potrebu patriť, ktorá ich motivuje k vyhľadávaniu sociálnych interakcií a vytváraniu blízkych a zmysluplných vzťahov s ostatnými.

\subsection{Obmedzenie v hrách}

\subsection{Využitie zvuku v hrách}
Pre mnoho ľudí je hudba v hrách oproti hudbe využitej vo filmoch na nerozoznanie.

\subsection{Tvorba príbehu}
Neoddeliteľnou súčasťou každej kvalitnej hry je dobrý príbeh. Vo väčšine prípadov je dôležité dbať dôraz na to, aby mali hráči dostatočnú kontrolu nad vývojom deja hry a pociťavali určitú obtiažnosť, ktorá ich nepriamo donucuje k tomu, aby sa zlepšovali. Prirodzená túžba človeka porozumieť svojmu svetu je taká silná, že ak sa herní dizajnéri zrieknu všetkej autorskej zodpovednosti a pokúsia sa vytvoriť hru bez príbehu, hráči do hry aj tak vnútia príbeh, bez ohľadu na to, či ho dizajnéri brali do úvahy. 

\section{Hra}

\subsection{Vplyv hier na ľudí a ich rozvoj}

\subsection{Spoločnosti zamerané na vývoj hier}

\subsection{Rozdelenie hier podľa ich zamerania}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `# # #` in line 86 cause an error

Comment: Please also clean up you tags, miktex and overleaf kind of contradict each other ....

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I removed those # # # and also removed the tags but it didnt solve my problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to show a [mre] which allows us to reproduce your actual issue.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I tried to edit it, hopefully it will help you in finding out what my problem actually is.

Comment: You sure you can't trim the code down more while still reproducing the problem. Are images we don't have access to or a bibliography file which we don't have, really necessary?

Comment: .... and I'm still confused by your usage of both the overleaf and miktex tags. Overleaf does not use miktex at all....

Comment: Okay I already tried to did it even more readable for you. I dont understand what you mean by using miktex and overleaf tags. If you mean those # # # I couldn't even see the in my code. And I'm using MikTex for this work.

Comment: I'm referring to the tags of your question https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJ5Ui.png If you are using miktex, you should remove the overleaf tag.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz okay I already removed it, sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: I still can't fully test your code, as it includes files like your bibliography, which we don't have, but the rest works fine for me. Is your tex distribution up to date? A couple of weeks ago, there was a bug in babel, but afaik, this has already been fixed.

Comment: bibliography was deleted finally, I'm new at it so it takes me more time to realize some things. Yes, I've updated it today and (at least I think it was right away after) after it I couldn't compile it to pdf.

Comment: Great! Finally a common starting point. Can you show your .log file so we can see which package versions you use?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz This is what it says in the beginning of my .log file: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.1) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.11.16)  16 NOV 2022 11:36                                                                   Sorry for late answer, but I had my class until know.

Comment: After I tagged "\usepackage[slovak]{babel}" it's working, but it won't translate Figure (while importing PDF's to my Latex document) into Slovak language.

Comment: Try this comment https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62386479#62386479

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz should I use it like that?                                         add \def\BabelCaseHack{\usepackage[slovak]{babel}} or put it bellow or on the top of it? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: No, `\def\BabelCaseHack{}\usepackage[slovak]{babel}`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665414/36296

Comment: Now, it's everything working. Thank you a lot for your help! I appreciate it so much! With greetings, Apolo

Comment: I had the same problem. Just removed the babel package and voilà. All back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem ; it seems to depend on the new babel package
(in my case, without the "\usepackage[french]{babel}" the compilation complete).

Comment: Yes, removing package "\usepackage[slovak]{babel}" helped me out aswell. Does it cause any side effects? Thanks for your answear